# How can I model synonyms with RDF/RDFS?

Tags: rdf, rdfs

How can I model synonyms with RDF/RDFS?

for example when I have two different divisions with different databases which have different terminologies for the same Things.

Comment: `owl:sameAs` — ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the same concept (aka class), just add another label

For instance, if you have a Class to represent a database system administrator, you could have 3 rdfs:label : "Database System Administrator", "DBA", "Database Administrator"

Alternatively, you could add another class, let say for DBA, and assert that class "DBA" is same as class "Database Administrator" (using owl:sameAs)

Hope this answers your question.
Nicolas Leveque

Answer (score 0):

There are several facilities in RDFS and OWL that allow linking individuals, classes, and properties this way.

For individuals, plain RDFS has no way of specifying that two resources are the same thing. OWL does have, however, `owl:sameAs`, specifying that the two resources denote the same individual (which can also be used on classes and properties but only in OWL Full).

For classes and properties, RDFS has `rdfs:subClassOf` and `rdfs:subPropertyOf`. These normally mean subset/implication, but using them in both directions makes the two classes/properties equivalent. OWL has `owl:equivalentClass` and `owl:equivalentProperty` as shortcuts for that.